# React Tab component not updating active tab when Redux store value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, chakra-ui

I am using the Chakra UI Tab component in my React application. I have a number value stored in Redux, and I want to change the active tab based on this value. However, when I update the number value in the store, the active tab does not change accordingly. How can I fix this issue?

Here is the code for `MyTabs` component:

```
function MyTabs() {
  const number = useSelector(selectnumber);

  console.log(number);

  return (
    <Tabs defaultIndex={number}>
      <TabPanels>
        <TabPanel>
          <Image boxSize="200px" fit="cover" src="" />
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          <Image boxSize="200px" fit="cover" src="" />
        </TabPanel>
      </TabPanels>
      <TabList>
        <Tab>Naruto</Tab>
        <Tab>Sasuke</Tab>
      </TabList>
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `defaultIndex` prop is:

> The initial index of the selected tab (in uncontrolled mode)

See [Controlled and uncontrolled components](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components) and [Default Values](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) doc:

> In the React rendering lifecycle, the `value` attribute on form elements will override the value in the DOM. With an uncontrolled component, you often want React to specify the initial value, but leave subsequent updates uncontrolled. To handle this case, you can specify a `defaultValue` attribute instead of `value`. **Changing the value of `defaultValue` attribute after a component has mounted will not cause any update of the value in the DOM.**

You can use [Controlled Tabs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/tabs#controlled-tabs)

```
const tabIndex = useSelector(selectnumber);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

<Tabs 
  index={tabIndex} 
  onChange={(index) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_TAB_INDEX', payload: { index } })}>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the active tab in your Chakra UI Tab component updates when the number value changes in Redux, you can use the useEffect hook provided by React. The useEffect hook allows you to perform side effects, such as updating the active tab, when specific dependencies change.

You can modify your MyTabs component as follows:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
    import { Tabs, TabList, Tab, TabPanels, TabPanel } from '@chakra-ui/react';
    import { selectNumber, updateNumber } from 'path/to/your/redux/slice';
    function MyTabs() {
      const number = useSelector(selectNumber);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      useEffect(() => {
        // Update the active tab index in Redux when the number changes
        dispatch(updateNumber(number));
      }, [number, dispatch]);
      return (
        <Tabs defaultIndex={number}>
          <TabPanels>
            <TabPanel>
              <Image boxSize="200px" fit="cover" src="" />
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel>
              <Image boxSize="200px" fit="cover" src="" />
            </TabPanel>
          </TabPanels>
          <TabList>
            <Tab>Naruto</Tab>
            <Tab>Sasuke</Tab>
          </TabList>
        </Tabs>
      );
    }**'
```

In this updated code, the useEffect hook is used to dispatch an action (updateNumber) whenever the number value changes. Ensure that you have implemented the corresponding action and reducer logic (selectNumber) in your Redux slice to handle the number updates.

By doing this, the active tab will be automatically updated based on the number value stored in Redux.

Comment: I doubt anyone would want to use `number` as a dependency for the `useEffect` hook callback to unconditionally update the `number` state. This code also won't change the active tab when the `number` state updates, which is what the OP is asking for help with.